# how can I center this html page using bootstrap only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on this simple page, and I'm looking at centering the page using bootstrap code only (if possible) This is what I got so far. I tried using `col-xl-offset-4`, but not working.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-xl-offset-4">
        <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Marcell Treville</h1>
        <h3 class="text-center"><em>This is a tribute page for the legendary painter "Marcell Treville"</em></h3>
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="">
          <p>this is some text describing the image</p>
          <h2>Here's a timeline of Dr. Marcell Treville</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><strong>1995</strong> item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by centering? Horizontal or vertical centering?

Comment: What are you trying to center? The entire HTML page or just the container? Are you wanting to center it within another container or just in relation to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

hi no need to use offsets.
try adding "text-center" to this div

html

```
<div class="col-xl-6 text-center"> .... </div>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap v4, just use `row justify-content-center` will do the trick.

> REF: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/
>
> [image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Marcell Treville</h1>
        <h3 class="text-center"><em>This is a tribute page for the legendary painter "Marcell Treville"</em></h3>
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="">
          <p>this is some text describing the image</p>
          <h2>Here's a timeline of Dr. Marcell Treville</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><strong>1995</strong> item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @miatech does this fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to offset by 3 because that would add up to 12.  If you offset by four you will have 4 'empty' col, a div in the next 6, and 2 more 'empty' cols after it.  What you want is 3-6-3. What you currently have is 4-6-2.

Comment: but still the text is showing to left... is not even moving

Comment: I just noticed that you are trying to use bootstrap 3 and col-xl.  Bootstrap 3 only uses up to col-lg.  Bootstrap 4 will have a col-xl.

Comment: You can do a google on adding your own xl classes, it's pretty straightforward.